# depth information of an image using bumblebee camera

Tags: c++, computer-vision

I am working with [bumblebee camera](http://www.ptgrey.com/products/stereo.asp) and I am very new to this field. Could someone please help me out with the extraction of depth information of an image.

Comment: 4 spaces in front of a line cause it to become formatted as code. You could remove those spaces to make this a little more readable.

Comment: What is a "bumblebee camera"?  Find out and linkify that phrase.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be some SDK from [point grey](http://www.ptgrey.com/products/stereo.asp) (makers of the Bumble bee)

Failing that pretty much any image processing library does [stereo reconstruction](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html)

Comment: Thank you for ur reply and yeah i do have Flycapture SDK and I am able to obtain the disparity mapping directly but with that information how do we calculate the depth of an image.

Comment: In openCV it's http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#reprojectimageto3d the references should point you to the algorithms

Comment: Hi, what does literally the depth of an image mean? is it the distance of an object from the camera or if not, what is that?